# Access Bluemix CLI from private VLAN

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-tools

I want to access the basic Bluemix CLI to do some infrastructure management (formerly softlayer)  however the way I have configured my network is that all virtual machines are on a private VLAN with no access to the public internet, thus the Bluemix CLI tool is trying to access API endpoint:

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1

however it is failing:

Get https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getCurrentUser.json: dial tcp 66.228.119.120:443                              : i/o timeout

this is just trying to issue the preliminary **bx sl init**  command with my username and API key I generated in the portal.

How does one access this from a private VLAN?  Is is possible? or are all tools available to me useless?

Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

Try by using the following endpoints for private networks

```
https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3
```

or

```
https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/blog/klaude/its-time-bust-out-private-network/

Comment: ah this helps a great deal.  one thing i couldn't find is are there any programmatic clients which can use this framework?  ideally python or java to issue these commands outside of just shell scripting/bash sessions ?

Comment: You can use softlayer libraries which can be downloaded from here https://github.com/softlayer, there are libraries for python, java, go, php, etc. Also you can find documentation about the API and examples here https://softlayer.github.io/